# Can we place two exact cubes between two exact neighbor squares?

Tags: proof-writing

In other words are there any integers that satisfy the following inequality: n² < a³ < b³ < (n +1)²?
I have no idea how to solve the problem? Can someone give me a hint?
I know this question is related to proof by contradiction.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Look at $(\sqrt {a+1})^3-(\sqrt a)^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by 
$$ f(x) \colon= x^3 \ \qquad \mbox{ for all } x \in \mathbb{R}$$ 
is a *strictly increasing* function with range equal to $\mathbb{R}$.

So, for $n = 0$, for example, there are two (in fact infinitely many) real numbers $a$ and $b$ cuthat $$ n^2 = 0 < a^3 < b^3 < 1 = 1^2 = (n+1)^2. $$

However, we cannot have integers $a$, $b$, and $n$ such that 
$$ n^2 < a^3 < b^3 < (n+1)^2. $$
In oder to show this, note that, for any integer $k$, we have
$$ (k+1)^2 - k^2 = 2k+1, $$
while 
$$ (k+1)^3 - k^3 = 3k^2 + 3k + 1 > 2k+1.$$
Thus the cubes of integers change much more rapidly than do the squares.